# Angular4 nav nav-tabs style not working

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, angular

I am using Angular4 and the `nav nav-tabs` style doesn't seems working, all I get is the unordered vertical list as below image -

[image]

My component code for the tabs is -

```
@Component({
selector: 'tabs',
template:`
<ul id="tabs" class="nav nav-tabs" data-tabs="tabs">
  <li *ngFor="let tab of tabs" (click)="selectTab(tab)" [class.active]="tab.active" data-toggle="tab">
    <a href="#profile" data-toggle="tab">{{tab.title}}</a>
  </li>
</ul>
<ng-content></ng-content>
`,
styleUrls: ['./css/bootstrap.min.css','./css/paper-dashboard.css','./css/themify-icons.css','./css/animate.min.css']
})
```

When I inspect the ul element they do have the class as below screen shot -

[image]

For the tabs I am using [Learning Angular: Creating a tabs component](https://juristr.com/blog/2016/02/learning-ng2-creating-tab-component/)

Comment: Clearly it's a lack of CSS. Could you give us the code of your Component please ?

Comment: Thanks for prompt response, I have included the component code.

Comment: So by the look of the `styleUrls` property, I assume you have a folder `css` **in the same folder your component is**, and that this folder contains all the required styles ?

Comment: Yes it does in fact all other styles are getting applied which belong to bootstrap, the tab contents are getting displayed properly.

Comment: And what happens if you inspect them ? They have absolutely no class ?

Comment: It does have `nav nav-tabs` class as modified in question.

Comment: But those 2 classes have absolutely no style ? Or they have the style but it's not applied ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/148031/discussion-between-jeet-and-trichetriche).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The path to the bootstrap css file inside the `styleUrls` field was wrong.